# How do you pass array values to an ARM template using -TemplateParameterObject

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I am deploying an ARM template via Powershell and using the following commands.  The parameter in the ARM template is of type array and is named "backendIPAddresses". The below doesnt work.  How can I pass parameters of type array to the template using -TemplateParameterObject

```
$Parameters = @{
    "backendIPAddresses" = "10.20.4.7", "10.20.4.8"
}

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroup" -TemplateUri $rg_templateuri  -TemplateParameterObject $Parameters
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your backendIPAddresses property in your object as an array.

```
$Parameters = @{
    backendIPAddresses = @("10.20.4.7", "10.20.4.8")
}
```